# Php cannot see many files included in a zip file

Tags: php, zip, xbrl

I'm reading files that are located inside a `.zip` archive (in this case an XBRL taxonomy) using PHP 7 and its `ZipArchive` functions, but a whole lot of files that I am sure are inside are simply skipped, ignored as they do not exist.

This is the result of running `zipinfo www.eba.europa.eu.zip` on the file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/336njdmfg8uaho8/output-zipinfo.txt?dl=0

This is the result of reading the content of the zip using the following code:

```
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    $zip->open("www.eba.europa.eu.zip");

    for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        echo 'Filename: ' . $zip->getNameIndex($i) . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7njkp5i92d68fxs/output-ziparchive.txt?dl=0

As you can see all the files with `finrep` in their name just are not present in the second test.

What could it be? Missing permissions on something? File size/number limit? Sorry for the Dropbox links, but the logs are both quite big considering the number of files.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The links points to txt files (as the filenames `output-zipinfo.txt` and `output-ziparchive.txt` show), but anyway if you can recommend me any place where I can create gists that are longer than 40K lines then I'll be happy to update the question  :)

Comment: Do you reproduce it with smaller zip files ? If possible, we would need a link to the zip file itself (or a test case which reproduce the issue)

Comment: Smaller zips seems to be working properly, the big zip file can be retireved at [the EBA website](https://www.eba.europa.eu/documents/10180/1397264/XBRL+Taxonomy+and+Supporting+Documents+2.4.1.1zip/ae0504b4-2070-4416-bf08-4657b06ee4ca) in a file called `www.eba.europa.zip`

Comment: I don't see any file named `www.eba.europa.zip` but I see `Taxonomy/FullTaxonomy.2.4.1.1.7z` which seems to contain the files you list (minus all the files in `__MACOSX/`). Do you work on a copy recompressed in zip format or was it a previous version of the document ?